Updating Arbitrary Weights in old code
I am currently in the process of updating an old Substrate Tutorial, so that I can continue my journey into the wide world of Blockchain development. The tutorial was built on Polkadot v0.9.28, and most of the work has involved updating dependencies, but I've reached a lesson (exercise 6) on weights that has me a little stumped.
Within test.rs there are many calls to the assert! macro, comparing weights. Some examples:
assert_eq!(weight, 10_000 + db_weights.reads(1));
assert!(weight1 < weight2);
assert!(weight1 > db_weights.writes(1));
assert_eq!(weight1, 100_000);

The issue Im running into is that weight is a struct and cant be compared or added to an int
To address the issue, I have changed the arguments within the assert! macros to look something like this:
assert_eq!(weight, Weight::from_parts(10_000, u64::MAX) + DbWeight::get().reads(1));
assert!(weight1.proof_size() < weight2.proof_size());
assert!(weight1.proof_size() > db_weights.writes(1).proof_size());
assert_eq!(weight1, Weight::from_parts(100_000, u64::MAX));

This got the compiler to build the lesson, but I have a feeling that it is not correct, and instead of proof_size maybe I should have used ref_time. But that also feels incorrect. Would the WeightToFeemethod be more suitable for this instance? I haven't been able to locate any documentation that talks about this change, and any insight would be appreciated.
Thanks!

The new Weight struct has functions specifically for comparing two weights:
https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/bp_messages/struct.Weight.html#
    /// Returns true if any of `self`'s constituent weights is strictly greater than that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn any_gt(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time > other.ref_time || self.proof_size > other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if all of `self`'s constituent weights is strictly greater than that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn all_gt(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time > other.ref_time && self.proof_size > other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if any of `self`'s constituent weights is strictly less than that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn any_lt(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time < other.ref_time || self.proof_size < other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if all of `self`'s constituent weights is strictly less than that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn all_lt(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time < other.ref_time && self.proof_size < other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if any of `self`'s constituent weights is greater than or equal to that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn any_gte(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time >= other.ref_time || self.proof_size >= other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if all of `self`'s constituent weights is greater than or equal to that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn all_gte(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time >= other.ref_time && self.proof_size >= other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if any of `self`'s constituent weights is less than or equal to that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn any_lte(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time <= other.ref_time || self.proof_size <= other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if all of `self`'s constituent weights is less than or equal to that of the
    /// `other`'s, otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn all_lte(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time <= other.ref_time && self.proof_size <= other.proof_size
    }

    /// Returns true if any of `self`'s constituent weights is equal to that of the `other`'s,
    /// otherwise returns false.
    pub const fn any_eq(self, other: Self) -> bool {
        self.ref_time == other.ref_time || self.proof_size == other.proof_size
    }

    // NOTE: `all_eq` does not exist, as it's simply the `eq` method from the `PartialEq` trait.

Truthfully, some of these assertions in the old tutorial seem pretty useless in terms of trying to represent anything meaningful.
I think it would be better to extract the intended meaning of those comparisons, and then try to create those tests from scratch with that in mind.

Thanks for your input! I was hoping to get the whole tutorial functional and send a push request so that this tool can continue to be used by others. I don't think that building tests from scratch is within my scope yet, so I may abandon that idea for the time being, skip this exercise, and learn about weights elsewhere.

The PBA lecture on Benchmarking and Weights can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLPYKN36HlU
